# Firebase Rules for object only for creator and admin user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, mobile-application

I am really confused with Firebase rules and need some help. I googled a lot but actually got only more confused and still don't get it work.

Lets say I have a Firebase db object like this:

```
root/orders/$id
```

and inside the `$id`, I have a child `user_id`:

```
root/orders/$id/user_id
```

Now I want a rule which only allow the user to READ his own orders (but not write anymore in existing once, how ever he need to create new once) and additional I want the users which are admins to READ/WRITE all orders at any time.

I come up with this so far

```
  "orders": {
    "$id": {
        ".read": "root.child('orders').child($id).child('user_id').val() == auth.uid || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == 'user_is_admin'",
        ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == 'user_is_admin'"          
        },
        ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == 'user_is_admin'",
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() == 'user_is_admin'",                  
        ".indexOn": ["status", "user_id"]
   },
```

My admins are marked as admins in my user table:

```
root/users/$id/admin (== user_is_admin)
```

My intention was for the first part to allow users with the same `auth.uid` as the requested `/orders/$id/user_id` to read their orders and for admins to read and write. The admin part is working, but my user has no access for some reason.

The second part was for admins to have read/write access to all orders (without specific `$id`) which also works fine plus a normal user need the write to CREATE a new order here.

To resume the admin part of my rules works, but the user part does not. 
1. my user cant read is own orders
2. my user cant create a new order

I would be really happy if somebody can help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Rules:**

The following rules should enforce the policies you've outlined in your question:

```
"orders": {
  "$id": {
    ".read":  "data.child('user_id').val() === auth.uid",
    ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.child('user_id').val() === auth.uid"
  },
  ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() === 'user_is_admin'",
  ".read":  "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('admin').val() === 'user_is_admin'",
  ".indexOn": ["status", "user_id"]
}
```

Note that Firebase security rules cascade, so once you've granted read/write permissions to admins for `orders`, you don't need to repeat the rules for `orders/$id`. (Something to remember - although it's not an issue with your rules - is that once you grant a permission on a parent you cannot revoke it on a child.)

The `orders/$id/.read` rule uses `data.child` to compare the `user_id` and the `auth.uid`. This is the same as your rule, it's just a little shorter and does not include the admin check (which cascades).

In addition to checking that `newData` (the value being written) contains the `user_id`, the `orders/$id/.write` rule checks to see that `data` (the previous value) does not exist. That will allow creates, but will deny updates and deletes.

**Orders for Users:**

As noted in your comment, it's not possible for a user to query a list of orders under the `orders` key, as the user won't have permission to read the orders of other users (they'd need to be readable to be filtered out). You could solve the problem by storing a mapping of orders by user, like this:

```
"orders": {
    "order_1": {
        "user_id": "user_1",
        ...
    },
    "order_2": {
        "user_id": "user_1",
        ...
    },
    "order_3": {
        "user_id": "user_2",
        ...
    }
},
"ordersByUser": {
    "user_1": {
        "order_1": true,
        "order_2": true
    },
    "user_2": {
        "order_3": true
    }
}
```

You can use Firebase's multi-location updates to make maintaining the mapping less tedious. For example, to add another order for `user_1`, you could do this:

```
firebase.database().ref().update({
    "orders/order_4": {
        "user_id": "user_1",
        ...
    },
    "ordersByUser/user_1/order_4": true
});
```

This would let users obtain a list of order IDs (and, from those, the orders themselves) and admin users could still obtain a list of all orders, etc.

Also, you should include a rule so that users can only read their own order IDs under `ordersByUser`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and it is all working as you explained. I do have now only another problem. In my app i get all orders from the user with `var ref_orders = firebase.database().ref('orders').orderByChild('user_id').equalTo(user_id);
      var obj = $firebaseArray(ref_orders);` and since this is not a specific order_id which is called (but a list of all from this user) which goes to /orders/ and not /orders/$id, I cant access the data.

How could I allow the user to get a list of his orders now?

Comment: You are great, thank you so much, this makes all more sense to me now. I appreciate your time and help. I will update all as you suggested.

Comment: One more thing about this @cartant, is there any way to see WHICH permission was denied during development? I have in the meanwhile pages of rules and validation and sometimes lose lots of time to figure out what actually was denied when many things come together. Is there something like an error log in firebase available?

Comment: I'm not aware of any log and as far as I know the only way to get some indication of which rule is effecting a denial is to use the Firebase console's simulator.

Comment: okay, thank you. So I need to copy my entire object json into the simulator and than see where it hangs. I cant help me but thinking that the entire rules/security system from firebase seems "overcomplicated". It is a lot of work to write all the rules for the entire system. The time you save with firebase to setup your db you lose on the security system. This should be much easier and simples to setup in my opinion. Thanks to you I get further here.